# Are video game reviews welcome on the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

The [Contribute](http://thesffblog.com/contribute/) page of the blog says this:

> Some suggested topics include:
>
> - Reviews of books, TV series, comics, or films (**sci-fi or fantasy game reviews are better suited over at [our cousin’s place](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/)**), whether something newly released, or a classic more people should know about.

Given that Stack Exchange has discontinued the standard community blog mechanism (and I'm not aware of a successor to Arqade's community blog), should we just absorb video games into the list of suggested media?  Or are games out of scope anyway (e.g. because a review will probably be more about gameplay than story)?  What about "story-only" reviews, where gameplay is ignored and the writer only discusses the story elements?

Either way, that parenthetical should probably be changed.

(Looking through the reviews tag, the second item is currently an *Assassin's Creed* review, but this is a red herring -- it's a review of the movie adaptation, not the games themselves.)

Comment: Just as an FYI, the contribute page hasn't been fully reworked. So it's it's good to ask, because we haven't had all those discussions yet.

Comment: I see that you (presumably) submitted a Gargoyles review last week. I didn't see it until today. In the future ping me via the sff blog chat channel. The article looks good, so I can publish it if it is ready, let me know.

Comment: @JackBNimble: Sorry for the confusion there.  You might want to update the Contribute page and/or [this answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/704/36526) to clarify that authors should ping you for new posts.  As far as whether it's ready - If you think it's in a good state now, please go ahead and publish it on whatever schedule(?) the blog uses.

Comment: @Kevin the contribute page does say to pop into the chat room and ping us to discuss it. But no matter. I have scheduled your article to publish on Monday, March 6.

Comment: @Kevin Your article is doing well, it has a few comments on the blog site (https://thesffblog.com/2017/03/gargoyles-a-review/) as well as comments on reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/5xy9y3/gargoyles_tv_series_a_review/)

Answer (score 17):

Since the blogs are now "unofficial" blogs, I think we can relax a bit on what we limit ourselves to. So, my opinion is, if it's an article you think would be of interest to *this community*, it's fair game for the blog.

In the case of a video game review, I think you'd have to be aware of who your target audience is. We're here because we like to watch/read/etc sci-fi and fantasy material. Some of us may *also* enjoy playing video games, but that's not the thing that brings *this* community together. So a mechanical review of the latest *CounterStrike* is probably not something we'd want.

On the other hand, there's plenty of sci-fi/fantasy themed games, and they share many of the same qualities as a movie. Reviews of *Witcher* games or *Elder Scrolls* games that discuss not just gameplay, but the story, characters, appearance, sound, etc. I think would be welcome.

The best thing I can recommend is just write and submit one to start with and see how it goes over. If people like it, we can publish more. If people don't like it, we'd probably want to pass on them.

Comment: +1 for mentioning *The Witcher*

Comment: Yeah it's pretty rare for game reviews to focus on the story and worldbuilding side of things rather than graphics and gameplay, so a review/article that treated a game as a work of fiction and reviewed its literary merits would seem like a good fit here as well as providing something different and interesting

Answer (score 16):

I have no objection to content based on a video game, but I would rather see content based on the story and the world, and not particularly the gameplay.

Comment: This is consistent with the [policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/320/31394) on video game questions on the main site.